# React-Native iOS accessibilityViewIsModal property doesn't work

Tags: ios, react-native, accessibility, voiceover

I am using Accessibility with VoiceOver in my app.
The problem is when i am using the `accessibilityViewIsModal` property with a `Modal` and the Modal is opened, VoiceOver reads the content behind the Modal.
According to the documentation:

> in a window that contains sibling views A and B, setting
>   accessibilityViewIsModal to true on view B causes VoiceOver to ignore
>   the elements in the view A. On the other hand, if view B contains a
>   child view C and you set accessibilityViewIsModal to true on view C,
>   VoiceOver does not ignore the elements in view A.

tried to do so but no success.

This is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'react-native-button';
import Modal from 'react-native-modalbox';
import Slider from 'react-native-slider';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';

var screen = Dimensions.get('window');

class AccessibilityApp extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      isDisabled: false,
      swipeToClose: true,
      sliderValue: 0.3
    };
  }

  onClose() {
    console.log('Modal just closed');
  }

  onOpen() {
    console.log('Modal just openned');
  }

  onClosingState(state) {
    console.log('the open/close of the swipeToClose just changed');
  }

  renderList() {
    var list = [];

    for (var i=0;i<50;i++) {
      list.push(<Text style={styles.text} key={i}>Elem {i}</Text>);
    }

    return list;
  }

  render() {
    var BContent = <Button onPress={() => this.setState({isOpen: false})} style={[styles.btn, styles.btnModal]}>X</Button>;

    return (
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
          <Button onPress={() => this.refs.modal3.open()} style={styles.btn}>Position centered + backdrop + disable</Button>
        <Modal accessibilityViewIsModal={true} style={[styles.modal, styles.modal3]} position={"center"} ref={"modal3"} isDisabled={this.state.isDisabled}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Modal centered</Text>
          <Button onPress={() => this.setState({isDisabled: !this.state.isDisabled})} style={styles.btn}>Disable ({this.state.isDisabled ? "true" : "false"})</Button>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  wrapper: {
    paddingTop: 50,
    flex: 1
  },

  modal: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  modal2: {
    height: 230,
    backgroundColor: "#3B5998"
  },

  modal3: {
    height: 300,
    width: 300
  },

  btn: {
    margin: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#3B5998",
    color: "white",
    padding: 10
  },

  btnModal: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  },

  text: {
    color: "black",
    fontSize: 22
  }

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AccessibilityApp', () => AccessibilityApp);
```

and this is the screenshot:

[image: my app screenshot]

Comment: I didn't use this feature before but it says `sibling views A and B`. Your Modal is child of the main view. So its like your Modal is the C view from the example. Wrapping Button sibling to Modal with a View might help. Its just a guess tho

Comment: @bennygenel I suspect you're right. You should convert it to an answer.

Comment: Thank you but it would be better if you answer your question with how you managed to get it work since I don't have enough knowledge in the topic. Mine was just a guess.

Comment: @bennygenel it didn't work .

Comment: Ah. @Maximtoyberman Have you tried setting `isAccessibilityElement` to `false` for the view underneath?

Comment: @MaximToyberman did you ever figure this out? I think it is a bug with RN. I am experiencing similar problems as well with RN and react-navigation where after navigating to a new screen, voiceover still reads elements from the previous screen.

Comment: @chillpenguin what is the problem exactly ? are you trying to read text in a modal ?

Comment: @MaximToyberman The issue I had has been fixed in the most recent versions of react-navigation.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when I am using the accessibilityViewIsModal property with a Modal and the Modal is opened, VoiceOver reads the content behind the Modal.

The only way to avoid VoiceOver checking other elements than those in the foreground is using the **[accessibilityViewIsModal](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18230.html#accessibilityViewIsModal)** iOS property of your modal view as you did in React-Native apparently.

The problem that you encounter may find its **source in the view hierarchy** itself as I always noticed in this case.

As you added an *iOS* tag, I wonder you understand this kind of programming and I suggest to:

- Watch this [WWDC excerpt](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/230/?time=2073) to find out the proper iOS implementation that may help with React-Native (???).
- Read this [article](http://ronnqvi.st/adding-accessible-behavior) in the **Implementing accessible modal views** section to understand the way this property works with a clever, interactive and pedagogical illustration.
- Take a look at this [site](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#modal-view) where useful examples are provided with helpful illustrations *(still for iOS but a React-Native enlightenment may come from here)*.